# Creating a triangular table

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, rotating

Is there a way to create something that looks like this?
[image]

I have looked at the `\rotatebox` command, but that will not get the same "jagged" edges on the bottom, and looked at [How to draw a diagonally-split grid with TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108472/how-to-draw-a-diagonally-split-grid-with-tikz) which seems applicable (especially in conjunction with the `\rotatebox`).

I was able to make this:

[image]

With code adapted from the link, but I have no idea how to customize it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.shapes}
\tikzset{
  decorate with/.style args={#1 separated by #2}{
    fill,
    decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=#1,shape size=1.5mm,
    shape sep={#2, between borders}}
  }
}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
   num quad/.initial=5,
   num quad/.get=\numquad,
   num quad/.store in=\numquad,
}

\begin{document}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.shapes}
\rotatebox{315}{\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5025cm,y=0.5025cm,line cap=round]
    \foreach \x [count=\xi] in {1,...,\numquad}{
      \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {\x,...,\numquad}{
        \node [draw, minimum size=0.5cm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt] (u-\xi\yi) at (\xi,-\yi) {};
      }
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @soandos I think, here you're better off with the `diamond` shape or a matrix-like approach. How’d you want to have your input?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel, I was in the middle and accidently clicked saved the intermediate.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `diamond` shape is only there for drawing and filling, the text is actually only a label (which is actually a node too) to the diamond node.

This works <s>best</s> only with an angle of 45.
One could also solve this with a custom coordinate system (*x* going ↗, *y* going ↘) instead of rotation, the squares/diamonds could have been drawn also with a rectangular path.

The size of the shape is manually set to

```
minimum size=1.414cm+0.4\pgflinewidth
```

The co-efficient of `\pgflinewidth` is found empirical and is chosen so that the lines overdraw eachother, as a `grid` would do that.

**Update:**
The macro that is used by `remember` isn't remembered anymore after the loops. I'm using `global remember` for this. (The key `remember=\macro` is still needed since `global remember` doesn't apply the same parsing that `remember` does.)

To add *j →*  and *m →* I've used my custom `/utils/exec={<cond>}{<true keys>}{<false keys>}` key to add a label to a label. (We could've used `\ifnum` here, too, or we could also replace the `\ifnum`s by `/utils/if`s.)

The `mathtools` package is loaded for `\mathrlap` to easily place the →-labels.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\makeatletter
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/foreach}{
  global remember/.code=%
    \pgfutil@append@tomacro{\pgffor@remember@code}{\gdef\noexpand#1{#1}}}
\pgfqkeys{/utils}{if/.code n args={3}{%
  \pgfmathifthenelse{#1}{1}{0}\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0 
  \expandafter\pgfutil@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\pgfutil@firstoftwo\fi
  {\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    rotate=-45,
    every label/.append style={text depth=+0pt},
    label position=center,
    every cell/.style={fill=gray!25},
    column 3/.style={fill=red!25},
    row 5/.style={fill=green!25},
    cell 2-2/.style={fill=gray},
    cell 3-2/.style={fill=gray!50},
    ]
\foreach \jRow[count=\jCount from 1, remember=\jCount, global remember=\jCount] in {%
        0,%
        {15750,0},%
        {7875,2625,0},%
        {9375,4375,750,0},%
        {11875,7125,2500,1000,0},%
        {15125,10500,5375,3500,5000,0}%
    } {
    \foreach \mCell[count=\mCount from 1, remember=\mCount] in \jRow {
        \node[
            diamond,
            minimum size=1.414cm+0.4\pgflinewidth,
            draw,
            every cell/.try,
            row \jCount/.try,
            column \mCount/.try,
            cell \jCount-\mCount/.try,
            label={\pgfmathprintnumber{\mCell}},
            alias=@lastnode,
            alias=@lastrow-\mCount
        ] at (\mCount-.5,\jCount-.5) {};
        \ifnum\mCount=1
            \path [late options={name=@lastnode,
              label={
                [/utils/if={\jCount==1}%
                  {label={[rotate=45,anchor=south]above left:$j\mathrlap{{}\to}$}}{}]
                above left:$\jCount$}}];
        \fi
    }
        \path [late options={name=@lastnode, label=below:$A_\jCount$}];
    }
    \foreach \jCountExtra in {1,...,\jCount}
        \path [late options={name=@lastrow-\jCountExtra, label={
          [/utils/if={\jCountExtra==1}%
            {label={[rotate=-45,anchor=south]above right:$m\mathrlap{{}\to}$}}{}]
           above right:$\jCountExtra$}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This solved the issue: https://www.reddit.com/r/LaTeX/comments/f5xrz6/creating_a_triangular_table_undefined_control/

Comment: How about adding the table name, and `i` `j` indices?

Comment: @RavindraRanwala I've updated the answer with my custom `global remember` key and as a suggestion I added the indices *j*  and ***m***.

Answer (score 18):

TikZ has a `rotate` option. Here is an example:

```
% without rotate
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0, -1)}]
    \path (0.5, -0.5) node{1} ++(1, 0) node{2};
    \path (-0.5, 0.5) node{1} ++(0, 1) node{2};
    \draw (0, 2) grid (2, 0);
    \node at (0.5, 0.5) {$12.34$};
    \node at (2.5, 2.5) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

% with rotate
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0, -1)}, rotate=-45]
    \path (0.5, -0.5) node{1} ++(1, 0) node{2};
    \path (-0.5, 0.5) node{1} ++(0, 1) node{2};
    \draw (0, 2) grid (2, 0);
    \node at (0.5, 0.5) {$12.34$};
    \node at (2.5, 2.5) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And the results:

[image]

---

### Update:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0, -1)}, rotate=-45]
    \path (0.5, -0.5) node{1} ++(1, 0) node{2};
    \path (-0.5, 0.5) node{1} ++(0, 1) node{2};
    \foreach \y in {0,...,2} {
        \foreach \x in {0,...,\y} {
            \draw (\x, \y - \x) rectangle +(1, 1);
        }
    }
    \node at (0.5, 0.5) {$12.34$};
    \node at (2.5, 2.5) {$A_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: How can I remove the bottom two lines, and then put the bottom labels at the bottom of the other cells?

Comment: @soandos: Just replace the line of `grid` with your line drawing code (a `\foreach` is required).

Comment: mind editing your answer to explain?

Comment: OK, wait a minute

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `nicematrix`. The tabular is constructed as a classical tabular. Then it is rotated by -45°. Each cell of the tabular is rotated by 45° in order to have horizontal text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,collcell}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-col = \rotatebox{45}{\arabic{iRow}},
    code-for-first-row = \rotatebox{45}{\arabic{jCol} \rule[-5mm]{0mm}{5mm}}
  }

\newcolumntype{K}{>{\collectcell\Rotate}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand{\Rotate}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\OnlyMainNiceMatrix{\rule[-10.6mm]{0mm}{21.2mm}\clap{#1}}}}

\rotatebox{-45}
{
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{NiceTabular}{KKKKKK}%
  [ hvlines,corners=SE,first-row,first-col,columns-width=15mm ]
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor{gray!10}
  \cellcolor{gray!80}{5-2,2-3}
  \cellcolor{gray!60}{4-2,2-4}
  \cellcolor{gray!40}{3-2,2-5}
\Body
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
& 15.125 & 10.500 & 5.375 & 3.500 & 5.000 & 0 \\
& 11.875 & 7.215 & 2.500 & 1.000 & 0 \\
& 9.375 & 4.375 & 750 & 0 \\
& 7.875 & 2.625 & 0 \\
& 15.750 & 0 \\
& 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style = {below,rotate=45}]
  \node at (7-|2) {$A_1$} ; 
  \node at (6-|3) {$A_2$} ; 
  \node at (5-|4) {$A_3$} ; 
  \node at (4-|5) {$A_4$} ; 
  \node at (3-|6) {$A_5$} ; 
  \node at (2-|7) {$A_6$} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

You can also put the instructions `\cellcolor` in the main tabular, that is to say in the corresponding cells as you would do with the command `\cellcolor` of `colortbl`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz,collcell}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions
  {
    code-for-first-col = \rotatebox{45}{\arabic{iRow}},
    code-for-first-row = \rotatebox{45}{\arabic{jCol} \rule[-5mm]{0mm}{5mm}}
  }

\newcolumntype{K}{>{\collectcell\Rotate}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcommand{\Rotate}[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\OnlyMainNiceMatrix{\rule[-10.6mm]{0mm}{21.2mm}\clap{#1}}}}

\rotatebox{-45}
{
\tabcolsep=0pt
\begin{NiceTabular}{KKKKKK}%
  [ hvlines,corners=SE,first-row,first-col,columns-width=15mm, colortbl-like ]
\CodeBefore
  \arraycolor{gray!10}
\Body
& 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
& 15.125 &  10.500 &  5.375 & 3.500 & 5.000 & 0 \\
& 11.875 & 7.215 & \cellcolor{gray!80} 2.500 & \cellcolor{gray!60} 1.000 & \cellcolor{gray!40}0 \\
& 9.375 & \cellcolor{gray!40} 4.375 & 750 & 0 \\
& 7.875 & \cellcolor{gray!60} 2.625 & 0 \\
& 15.750 & \cellcolor{gray!80} 0 \\
& 0 \\
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [every node/.style = {below,rotate=45}]
  \node at (7-|2) {$A_1$} ; 
  \node at (6-|3) {$A_2$} ; 
  \node at (5-|4) {$A_3$} ; 
  \node at (4-|5) {$A_4$} ; 
  \node at (3-|6) {$A_5$} ; 
  \node at (2-|7) {$A_6$} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.