# How to draw a hazard diamond (like the one from National Fire Protection Association) in LaTeX?

Tags: color, shapes

Is it possible to make a diamond like the National Fire Protection Association in tex? I made a table using xcolor package with [colortbl].
[image: NFPA]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! On this platform, questions about how to draw specific graphics by just posting an image of the desired result are typically considered to be merely requests for “do it for me”. So, please post a minimal compilable document showing that you’ve tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. However, you should have a look at `tikz`.

Comment: … or look at [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110820/creating-a-triangular-table).

Comment: Somewhat related [tikz pgf - Creating a triangular table - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110820/creating-a-triangular-table) except for the coloring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote some macros for easy use of this diamond:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tgheros,tikz}

\newcommand{\nowater}{\huge%
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0) {W};
  \draw[line width=.1ex] (-.55em, 0) -- (.55em, 0);
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\radioactive}{%
 \raisebox{.5ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7, rotate=60]
  \fill (0, 0) circle (.1);
  \fill (0:.15) arc (0:60:.15) -- (60:.5) arc (60:0:.5) -- cycle;
  \fill (120:.15) arc (120:180:.15) -- (180:.5) arc (180:120:.5) -- cycle;
  \fill (240:.15) arc (240:300:.15) -- (300:.5) arc (300:240:.5) -- cycle;
 \end{tikzpicture}}%
}

\newcommand{\hazarddiamond}[4]{\sffamily\huge%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=225]
  \fill[red!75] (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
  \fill[blue!75] (1, 0) rectangle (2, 1);
  \fill[yellow!75] (0, 1) rectangle (1, 2);
  \draw (0, 2) grid (2, 0);
  \node at (0.5, 0.5) {#1};
  \node at (1.5, 0.5) {#2};
  \node at (0.5, 1.5) {#3};
  \node at (1.5, 1.5) {\large#4};
 \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\hazarddiamond{0}{0}{0}{}

\hazarddiamond{3}{1}{2}{\nowater}

\hazarddiamond{2}{4}{3}{\radioactive}

\hazarddiamond{4}{3}{3}{COR}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

An optimized solution that uses `pic`s instead of nesting `tikzpictures`, which is probably more robust:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,tgheros}

\tikzset{
    hazard diamond/.style={
        rotate=315,
        baseline=-0.5ex,
        execute at begin node={
            \sffamily
        },
        every node/.style={
            font=\huge
        }
    },
    text/.pic={
        \node[font=\large] at (0,0) {#1};
    },
    no water/.pic={
        \node at (0,0) {W};
        \draw[line width=.2ex] (-1em,0) -- (1em,0);
    },
    radioactive/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[x=0.2, y=0.2]
            \fill (0,0) circle[radius=10];
            \fill (0:15) arc[start angle=0, end angle=60, radius=15] 
                -- (60:52) arc[start angle=60, end angle=0, radius=52] -- cycle;
            \fill (120:15) arc[start angle=120, end angle=180, radius=15] 
                -- (180:52) arc[start angle=180, end angle=120, radius=52] -- cycle;
            \fill (240:15) arc[start angle=240, end angle=300, radius=15] 
                -- (300:52) arc[start angle=300, end angle=240, radius=52] -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
    },
    biohazard/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[x=0.2, y=0.2]
            \clip 
                (90:30) circle[radius=19]
                (210:30) circle[radius=19]
                (330:30) circle[radius=19];
            \fill 
                (0:27) 
                    arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=27] -- (0:20)
                    arc[start angle=360, end angle=0, radius=20] -- cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[x=0.2, y=0.2]
            \clip 
                (0:52) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=52]
                (90:5) -- ++(0:-1) -- ++(90:27) -- ++(0:-3) -- ++(90:20) -- ++(0:8) 
                    -- ++(90:-20) -- ++(0:-3) -- ++(90:-27) -- (90:5)
                (210:5) -- ++(120:-1) -- ++(210:27) -- ++(120:-3) -- ++(210:20) -- ++(120:8) 
                    -- ++(210:-20) -- ++(120:-3) -- ++(210:-27) -- (210:5)
                (330:5) -- ++(240:-1) -- ++(330:27) -- ++(240:-3) -- ++(330:20) -- ++(240:8) 
                    -- ++(330:-20) -- ++(240:-3) -- ++(330:-27) -- (330:5);
            \begin{scope}
                \clip 
                    (0:52) arc[start angle=0, end angle=360, radius=52]
                    (0:6) arc[start angle=360, end angle=0, radius=6]
                    (90:51) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-270, radius=21]
                    (210:51) arc[start angle=210, end angle=-150, radius=21]
                    (330:51) arc[start angle=330, end angle=-30, radius=21];
                \fill 
                    (90:22) circle[radius=30]
                    (210:22) circle[radius=30]
                    (330:22) circle[radius=30];
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\newcommand{\hazarddiamond}[5][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[hazard diamond,#1]
        \fill[red!75] (0,0) rectangle (-1,1);
        \fill[blue!75] (0,0) rectangle (-1,-1);
        \fill[yellow!75] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \draw (-1,-1) grid (1,1);
        \node at (-0.5,0.5) {#2};
        \node at (-0.5,-0.5) {#3};
        \node at (0.5,0.5) {#4};
        \pic at (0.5,-0.5) {#5};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

abc \hazarddiamond{4}{3}{3}{text={COR}} def

\hazarddiamond{4}{3}{3}{no water}

\hazarddiamond{4}{3}{3}{radioactive}

\hazarddiamond{4}{3}{3}{biohazard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,txfonts,stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\borderdiamond[2]{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries\sffamily#2}}{%
    \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}%
    {\scalebox{2.3}{\color{#1}$\Diamondblack$}}%
    {\scalebox{2.4}{$\Diamondblack$}}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stacktype{S}
\stackon[-9.7pt]{\smash{\borderdiamond{blue}{0}\kern-2.3pt\borderdiamond{yellow}{0}}}
  {\stackanchor[-.3pt]{\borderdiamond{red}{0}}{\borderdiamond{white}{}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]