# Formatting Safety messages

Tags: technical-drawing

In technical documentation the appearance of safety messages is regulated, e.g. ANSI Z535. I was wondering if anyone is aware of an implementation of such a norm in LaTeX. If not would anyone be interested in such a task? It is currently beyond my skills but perhaps with some help from the others...
Any feedback is much appreciated.
Szymon

Comment: You need to provide more detail as to what these "safety messages" look like, since we don't know much about ANSI Z535... visuals will help clarify the problem and provide solutions.

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. I am not aware of anything of the sort existing. If you need a specific sign my go-to would be `tikz` package like in the following solution https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391423/how-to-draw-a-hazard-diamond-like-the-one-from-national-fire-protection-associa

Comment: Also this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159669/how-to-print-a-warning-sign-triangle-with-exclamation-point

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I think the post provided by Den points in the right direction. I think there are two difficulty levels to this task

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I think the post provided by @Elad Den points in the right direction. Let me explain the concept. Safety messages are divided into several classes (**Danger, Warning, Caution** and **Notice**) depending on some criteria such as likely of a situation occurring, possible implications to affected people or equipment. The class of the safety message defines the signal word, e.g. Danger, Warning and the color if the header. Each safety message needs also to contain the following elements: **signal word, type and source of danger, possible consequences, how to avoid it.**

Comment: It would be great if in the first step I could achieve the following: define a command that would require these four fields and render them with the right color/symbol depending on the choice of the class element

Comment: Since the signal words are regulated also in other languages it would be great if the command change the output depending for example on the `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`. Does this make sense? :-)

Comment: One more level of complexity safety messages can be block elements (in XML sense) or inline elements :-)

Answer (score 1):

I created a style to address these requirements. If anyone is interested, the code can be found here: https://github.com/sz-slodowicz/Safety_messages.