# Create a House of Quality (HoQ) aka Product Planning Matrix (PPM) for a Quality Function Deployment (QFD)

Tags: tables

I'm supposed to do a House of Quality diagram (HoQ) for one of my classes and I don't know how to do it. It's supposed to be done in LaTeX and my team and I don't know what to do.

For your information, here's the HoQ example we were provided:

[image]

There are two problematic parts

1. The triangular table at the top
2. Joining all the tables together

How are we supposed to do it?

The teacher gave us a `.pdf` file for the example, the `.tex` file where the example comes from is lost, he's not the one that made it and nobody knows who made it nor how to do a HoQ.

I think it was made combining a triangular table like [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110820/creating-a-triangular-table). I know how to do it. The problem is combining it to another table.

PS: my first language is French, so I'm sorry if I made some mistakes while writing.

Comment: The example comes from Google images. However, the example in that we were provided was made in LaTeX, I'm totally positive about that.

Comment: There's way more lines in the example that I provided than our HoC

Comment: Good idea. Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it *possible* to generate this with LaTeX? Yes. Am I convinced that LaTeX is the best tool for that? No. Here is an existence proof. Please forgive me, I do not know French, and I am not good at typing in things from a screen shot. I also stopped adding the triangles, circles and so on after I added sufficiently many.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,myfit/.style={fill=white,draw,line width=\mylinewidth,
 inner sep=-0.5*\mylinewidth,fit=#1},
 circ/.style={path picture={\draw circle (0.3em);}},
 circdot/.style={path picture={\draw circle (0.3em); 
 \fill circle (0.1em);}},
 trian/.style={path picture={\draw (-30:0.3em) -- (90:0.3em) -- (210:0.3em) --cycle ;}},
 ]
 \def\mylinewidth{1pt}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes, nodes={draw,line width=\mylinewidth,minimum width=1.6em,
 minimum height=1.6em, anchor=center},column sep=-\mylinewidth,
 ,row sep=-\mylinewidth,%nodes in empty cells,
 row 3/.style={nodes={rotate=90,minimum width=9em,minimum height=1.6em}},
 row 11/.style={nodes={rotate=90,minimum width=9em,minimum height=1.6em}},
 column 3/.style={nodes={align=left,text width=11em,}}](mat) {
    & & & ~ & ~& ~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
    & & & ~ &~ & ~& ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ &~ \\
    & & & choix du chapteur & I don't know & French so I just & add bla bla   bla 
    & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[circ]| ~ & ~& ~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[circ]| ~ & |[circdot]|~& ~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[circ]| ~ & ~& |[circdot]|~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[circ]| ~ & ~& ~ & |[circdot]|~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[trian]| ~ & ~& ~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & |[circ]| ~ & |[circ]|~& |[trian]|~ & |[trian]|~& |[circdot]|~& |[trian]|~& ~&~ \\
   ~ & ~& alimentation & ~ & ~& ~ & ~& ~& ~& ~&~ \\
    & & & choix du chapteur & I don't know & French so I just & add bla bla   bla 
    & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla  & bla bla bla bla \\
 };
 \node[myfit=(mat-1-4) (mat-1-11)] {thermometre};
 \node[myfit=(mat-2-4) (mat-2-7)] {capteur};
 \node[myfit=(mat-2-8) (mat-2-9)] {etal};
 \node[myfit=(mat-10-1) (mat-4-1)] (aux1){};
 \node[rotate=90] at (aux1){mesure};
 \node[myfit=(mat-7-2) (mat-4-2)] (aux2){};
 \node[rotate=90] at (aux2){senseur};
 \node[myfit=(mat-9-2) (mat-8-2)] (aux3){};
 \node[rotate=90] at (aux3){conv.};
 \node[rotate=90] at (mat-10-2) {aff};
 % etc.
 \foreach \X in {4,...,11}
 {\draw[line width=\mylinewidth] (mat-1-\X.north west)
 -- (intersection cs:first line={(mat-1-\X.north west)--($(mat-1-\X.north west)+(45:5)$)},
 second line={(mat-1-11.north east)--($(mat-1-11.north east)+(135:5)$)});
 \draw[line width=\mylinewidth] (mat-1-\X.north east)
 -- (intersection cs:first line={(mat-1-\X.north east)--($(mat-1-\X.north east)+(135:5)$)},
 second line={(mat-1-4.north west)--($(mat-1-4.north west)+(45:5)$)});
 }
 \begin{scope}[shift={(mat-1-4.north west)},
 x={(45:{sqrt(1/2)*1.6em})},y={(-45:{sqrt(1/2)*1.6em})}
 ] % define local coordinate system for easier access of the cells
 \begin{scope}[shift={(0.6,-0.5)}]
  \foreach \Coord in {(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(7,1),%
  (5,2),(4,3),(4,4),(5,5),(7,7)}
  {\node at \Coord {\checkmark};}
 \end{scope} 
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much! It's also easy to manipulate as I want!

Comment: \checkmark gives an error-- Undefined control sequence. [  {\node at \Coord {\checkmark};}]

Comment: @js-bibra \checkmark is found in amssymb package,  \usepackage{amssymb}